# Setting time with clock_settime without having root access

Tags: time, set

I have written a C program that syncs the time with the time from a GPS reciever. The computer is running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. The program uses clock_settime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &timespec) to set the time. The program is executed in a bash script, and I cannot use sudo as the script is launched by the use of a desktop file. Anyone has an idea ?

NB: The script is executing multiple programs, that I do not want to execute as root

Comment: Is there a reason you are not using an existing NTP solution for this?

Comment: Yes, the computer is not networked. I have previously used PPS signal and GPS data in connection with the NTP deamon for obtaining a very precise synchronisation, but from my experience it does not work properly if the difference between the system and gps time is large, the ntp daemon rejects the PPS source !

Comment: Finally found a way that worked ,, first tried with visudo, not working .. but a less safe way using the following directly in my scipt echo $PASSWORD | sudo -S /path/to/program. Not the best solution, but it works !

Comment: Use `sudo`: put the script where it can not be edited. Set up `/etc/sudoers` to have a rule for this script. Write a wrapper script to call it with `sudo`.

Comment: Don't put your password in a script. Configure `sudoers`. You can tell it to run a specified program with no password. You need root privileges to set it up, but not to run the script. If you do it right (don't let the user edit the script, ensure there are no root escalation bugs), then it is safe.

Answer (score 1):

Capabilities can be a solution.

Before running program, you can add a CAP_SYS_TIME capbilities to your program like the next.

```
sudo setcap CAP_SYS_TIME+ep  /path/to/program
```

Example in docker

```
sys@2a2618c145ed:~$ ./a_pr.out
clock_gettime : 1534915500.689625314
clock_gettime : 1534916100.690310388
clock_gettime : 1534915500.690651299
sys@2a2618c145ed:~$ ./test.run
clock_gettime : 1534915504.139181778
Error : clock_settime -1
clock_gettime : 1534915504.139337010
Error : clock_settime -1
clock_gettime : 1534915504.139341290
sys@2a2618c145ed:~$ filecap $(pwd)
file                 capabilities
/jeremy/a_pr.out     sys_time
sys@2a2618c145ed:~$
```

Addtionally, I'd like to recommend the below page : [Allow a specific user or group root access without password to /bin/date](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/78299/allow-a-specific-user-or-group-root-access-without-password-to-bin-date)

The next can be better.
    sudo setcap CAP_SYS_TIME+ei  /path/to/program

Comment: has to be statically linked (no scripts or dynamic libraries). So could be used for a `C`, `go`, or `rust`, program. If it does not, then check you have linked everything statically.