# Granting privileges using visudo still prevents user to execute command

Tags: sudo, privileges, buildroot

Following [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/78300/169815) solution, I want to grant to the user `daemon` the execution of `/bin/date`.
Here what I did:

1. find the user that `apache2` uses when spawning:

   ```
   # ps | grep httpd
   252 root     /usr/bin/httpd -k start
   260 daemon   /usr/bin/httpd -k start
   262 daemon   /usr/bin/httpd -k start
   264 daemon   /usr/bin/httpd -k start
   467 root     grep httpd
   ```
2. find the right path for `date`:

   ```
   # which date
   /bin/date
   ```
3. using `visudo` add the following lines:

   ```
   Cmnd_Alias DATE=/bin/date                                               
   daemon ALL=NOPASSWD: DATE
   ```
4. reboot
5. test the new privileges:

   ```
   # sudo -u daemon date -s "2023-09-09 10:16:00"
   date: can't set date: Operation not permitted
   Sat Sep  9 10:16:00 UTC 2023
   ```

Is there anything wrong in my syntax?
I also tried with:

```
ALL ALL=NOPASSWD: DATE
```

but it's the same.
It's a Buildroot environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the exact path matching the `sudoers` configuration. Your test is also back to front: starting from root, you need to become `daemon`, then try to run `sudo`.

```
sudo -u daemon sudo /bin/date -s "2023-09-09 10:16:00"
```

should work.

(Your current test tries to run `date` as the `daemon` user, which won’t work.)